# Share the output of one class to another class python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have two DNNs the first one returns two outputs. I want to use one of these outputs in a second class that represents another DNN as in the following example:

I want to pass the output (x) to the second class to be concatenated to another variable (v). I found a solution to make the variable (x) as a global variable, but I need another efficient solution

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        ..
    def forward(self, x):
        ..
        return x, z


class Net2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        ..
    def forward(self, v):
        y = torch.cat(v, x)
        return y
```

Comment: why not pass `x` into `Net2.forward` as an argument

Comment: @BatWannaBe do you mean def forward(self, v, x): in Net2  okay how can the Net2 class call variable x from the first class.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm thinking of normal function calls. `x1, z0 = net1.forward(x0)` then `y0 = net2.forward(v0, x1)`

Comment: @BatWannaBe  Okay x1 is the output of the first-class how can I call it in the forward function in the second-class

Comment: `x1` is passed into `Net2.forward` as an argument as shown...

Comment: @BatWannaBe I will try this and back to you asap. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have to rely on *global* variables, you need to solve this following common practices. You can pass both `v`, and `x` as parameters of the `forward` of `Net2`. Something like:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        z = x**2
        return x, z

class Net2(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x, v):
        y = torch.cat((v, x), dim=1)
        return y
```

With dummy data:

```
>>> net = Net()
>>> net2 = Net2()

>>> input1 = torch.rand(1,10)
>>> input2 = torch.rand(1,20)
```

First inference:

```
>>> x, z = net(input1)
```

Second inference:

```
>>> out = net2(x, input2)
>>> out.shape
torch.Size([1, 30])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did this solution and it works many thanks.